# How to use sudo -u on both sides of a pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sudo

I am doing a bit of PostgreSQL administration on OS X.
Sometimes I need to copy a database to another database, which I do as follows.

```
sudo -u _postgres pg_dump mydb > mydb.sql
sudo -u _postgres psql -d mydb-testing -f mydb.sql
```

But I would rather just do this

```
sudo -u _postgres pg_dump mydb | sudo -u _postgres psql -d mydb-testing
```

However when I do this I get asked for my password, but it is always refused as incorrect.

I am looking for a solution where I can run a command as the _postgres user on both sides of a pipe.

Comment: why not `sudo su` and then run?

Comment: @raam86 The _postgres user, as configured has no login shell `UserShell: /usr/bin/false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe

```
sudo -u _postgres pg_dump mydb | sudo -u _postgres psql -d mydb-testing
```

should work as long as you make sure that the `sudo`s won't ask for your password from your terminal simultaneously.

If I cache my sudo password, I can pipe normally from one sudo'ed command to another:

```
sudo -u root echo hello world | sudo -u root tr a-z A-Z #prints HELLO WORLD
```

Another option is to use one `sudo` to spawn a shell:

```
sudo -u _postgres sh -c 'pg_dump mydb | psql -d mydb-testing'
```

(
You can use a heredoc if you have lots of things to do in that shell:

```
sudo -u _postgres sh <<'SCRIPT' 
    pg_dump mydb | psql -d mydb-testing
SCRIPT
```

)

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand why I was getting incorrect password when I ran that command, because, as you pointed out it is simultaneously asking for the password. Is there any other way to cache the password without just running a dummy command? Thanks also for the shell spawning and heredoc elaboration. You've solved my issue.

Comment: @JasonS Run `sudo -v` ("validate") before the piped commands; that'll verify your credentials (i.e. ask for your password) and set the timestamp so it won't ask again for 5 minutes.